# How to create "statistics" for every table of a schema? (where statistics means 1 returned record per each table)

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

I have a schema `myschema` in which I have dozens of tables, each containing a specific column `maincolumn`. I would like to create a statistics of the whole schema, where I can see how many distinct values are in the `maincolumn` per each table.

I know I can list the tables in a schema as a result of this query:

```
SELECT tablename 
FROM pg_tables 
WHERE schemaname = 'myschema'
```

Results:

```
tablename
---------
table1
table2
table3
...
```

Also I can run the query for each table:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(maincolumn))  
FROM myschema.table1
```

Results:

```
count
-----
2972
```

But I wonder if there's a way to join these two tasks into one query, which would result this:

```
tablename | count
----------+------
table1    | 2972 
table2    |  542 
table3    | 1523 
....
```

A not so elegant solution would be to list all my tables, put the result in an Excel table and use `CONCATENATE` function to create a `SELECT` query to every table, and then I could run it line by line, but I would prefer an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need dynamic SQL for that, probably in a PL/pgSQL function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_counts() RETURNS TABLE (table_name text, count bigint)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   FOR table_counts.table_name IN
      SELECT t.table_name
      FROM information_schema.tables AS t
      WHERE t.table_schema = 'myschema'
        AND t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format(
                 'SELECT count(*) FROM myschema.%I',
                 table_counts.table_name
              ) INTO table_counts.count;

      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Also, this is quite expensive.

If approximate counts are good enough for you, try

```
SELECT c.relname, c.reltuples
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class AS c
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS n
      ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
WHERE n.nspname = 'myschema'
  AND c.relkind = 'r';
```

The result becomes more accurate if you run `ANALYZE` first.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I'll have to write a function. 
I tried your code but it says `type "regnamespace" does not exist`. I checked the type of **regnamespace**  column within **pg_catalog.pg_class**, and the type is **oid**. Anyway thanks for the answer. I'll try to write the function and post it here once it's done.

Comment: You must be using an old PostgreSQL version. I have adapted my query and added a function that you could use if you don't mind the expense.